# PHP magic method __set declared in abstract class avoid extended class property assignation

Tags: php, abstract-class, extends, magic-methods

I have a problem with a magic method __set() in an abstract class (Model), as i cant assign any property of the class that extend Model. Neither trying to print the name of the variable in the __set method:

```
abstract class Model
{
public $data;
public function __set($name, $value)
{
echo $name; $this->$name = $value;
}
}

class User extends Model
{
public $id;
}

$u = new User();
$u->data = "hello"; //print "data";
$u->id = 123; //print NOTHING.. WHY¿?
```

Comment: Didn't you define `id` in your `User` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__set` is called when you try to assign a value in undefined property. In your case `__set` will never be called because both of the properties are defined and exists.

[See here](http://codepad.org/6NBHcQkZ) the output is nothing for both of the properties and try with removing one of the property declaration part and see the output difference.